# Emulator terminated with exit code -1

Tags: android, emulation

2023-07-10 17:14:33,706 [ 363011]   INFO - #c.a.s.i.a.AvdManager - D:\android_SDK.android\avd\Ipad_API_28.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Ipad_API_28
2023-07-10 17:14:33,706 [ 363011]   INFO - #c.a.s.i.a.AvdManager - D:\android_SDK.android\avd\Ipad_API_28.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Ipad_API_28
2023-07-10 17:14:33,706 [ 363011]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Ipad_API_28 is online, assuming it's not
2023-07-10 17:14:36,153 [ 365458]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - D:\android_SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapstorage -avd Ipad_API_28 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-07-10 17:14:36,177 [ 365482]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-07-10 17:14:36,177 [ 365482]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Found systemPath D:\android_SDK\system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - IPv4 server found: 172.16.32.1
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Consent given for uploading crashreport 23074871-2129-4e99-bd49-c748a680b069 to https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2023-07-10 17:14:36,852 [ 366157]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2023-07-10 17:14:36,948 [ 366253]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Failed to open the vcpu devfs
2023-07-10 17:14:36,948 [ 366253]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Failed to open the vcpu
2023-07-10 17:14:36,948 [ 366253]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Failed to create HAX vcpu
2023-07-10 17:14:40,693 [ 369998]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2023-07-10 17:14:40,717 [ 370022]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appPluginAdvertiserExtensions took 12 ms
2023-07-10 17:14:40,834 [ 370139]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr
2023-07-10 17:14:57,350 [ 386655]   INFO - Emulator: Ipad API 28 - Process finished with exit code -1

I don`t no way,who can help me?